# How to list the linux partitions by their created/modified time?

Tags: linux, partition

Is there any command to list the linux partitions by their created/modified time.

Comment: As explained below there's a difference between a partition and a filesystem. Please edit your question and clarify whether it's about partitions or filesystems.

Answer (score 6):

I think neither the MBR nor the GPT include explicit timestamps,
so it's probably impossible to know when the disk was partitioned.

That said, you can extract information on when a *filesystem* was created on a partition, and because, *usually*, you create a partition and then create a filesystem soon after (and then leave them alone), you can use `dumpe2fs` (if the filesystem is `ext2`,`ext3` or `ext4`):

```
$> dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep create
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem created:       Thu Sep 28 12:14:05 2017
```

and get a good estimate on when a partition was created.

As for your question of a *list* of partitions, you can easily create a script to iterate through the partitions and extract the corrisponding "create time".